# Excel VBA checks cells in certain order before returning a value from one of them in another cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a row of 4 cells that contain either 3 0's and a number, or two numbers and 2 0's. I need excel to check the cells from left to right and if a cell contains a 0 move on to the next cell until it finds a number and then return that number in cell 5. Any help would be grately appreciated!!

My test Data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jORv.jpg)

Comment: 1. Please post some test data and expected output. 2. Please show what attempts you have made and specify why it is failing, including errors and on which line they error.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me, teach me to code, or show me where to start site.

Comment: I have been using the if then else function. But it only seems to evaluate the first cell. When it gets a true result it displays the cell value.

Comment: Please post test data and expected output with the formula you have tried in the Original Post using [edit].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter this formula in `Column E`,

```
=IF(A1=0,IF(B1=0,IF(C1=0,IF(D1=0,"All are Zeroes",D1),C1),B1),A1)
```

[image]

Comment: Gowtham Shiva worked like a charm you are a gentleman and a scholar!

Comment: @stuartbrookes Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula:

```
=INDEX($A1:$D1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A1:$D1)/($A1:$D1<>0),1))
```

[image]